# ActiveX textbox value looping

Tags: vba, for-loop, ms-word, textbox, activex

I'm trying to perform a loop on several activeX textboxes named q1, q2, q3 ... q11. Here's what I tried, but it didn't work:

```
For i = 1 To 11
    myValue(i) = ActiveDocument.q & i.Value
Next
```

I also tried `"q" & i`, `(q & i)`, `("q" & i)`, etc, but none of it worked either.

It does however work when I'm being specific:

```
ActiveDocument.q1.Value
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems we cannot do it easy way. The following sub works for me.

```
Sub tst()
Dim myValue(1 To 3)
Dim shp As InlineShape
Dim i As Long 'counter
On Error Resume Next    

For i = 1 To 3
    For Each shp In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
        If Not shp.OLEFormat Is Nothing And _
            shp.OLEFormat.ClassType = "Forms.TextBox.1" And _
            shp.OLEFormat.Object.Name = "q" & i Then
        myValue(i) = shp.OLEFormat.Object.Text
        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

If it does not work, try opening the **Immediate window** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>), step into the sub (<kbd>F8</kbd>), move to the `If` statement and try checking every `If` clause separately in the Immediate window like this:

```
?Not shp.OLEFormat Is Nothing
```

You should get `True` for all the three clauses. 
If this part is ok then look at what happens with the line where you put values to your array.

Comment: Hey ZygD! Just played around with it, and unfortunately no it doesn't. I placed a MsgBox at the end to see what comes out, but it turns out empty. is `Forms.TextBox.1` pointing to a specific textbox with number 1? Maybe that's why?

Comment: Nope, doesn't find anything, just loops and ends without even triggering the MsgBox (which is right after `myValue(i) = shp.OLEFormat.Object.Value`. Maybe it's because textboxes(q1-q11) are located in a table?

Comment: I've just put my textboxes into the table and it still works. Try stepping through the code (I have updated my answer) and tell me what you have. I've also changed `.Value` for `.Text`, but I don't put hopes in this small change.

Comment: Yeah I just did the same in a separate file and it worked both in and outside of a table.. something else might be causing it. But at least I know we're on the right track! I'll keep you posted. Thanks!!

Comment: It might be true that `shp.OLEFormat.ClassType = "Forms.TextBox.1"` causes problems. In **Locals** window you can travel all the way `shp.OLEFormat.ClassType` down and you will see what is the actual type of your textboxes.

Comment: I did what you said in Locals and it says `: ClassType : Forms.OptionButton.1" : String`. On the other hand, in the new empty file it says `: ClassType : "Forms.TextBox.1" : String`. So why is it identifying it how it should in the empty file and not in my working file? I do have that option button earlier in the file though, so that's obviously what's going on. Now, how do we skip it?

Comment: I'd say just remove the line `shp.OLEFormat.ClassType = "Forms.TextBox.1" And _` completely from the code. I have doubts that your "textbox" is actually a textbox, but if you say it, you know it :) If they are named q1, q2, q3, you should be fine and get the results written into the array anyway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73045/discussion-between-blackwind-and-zygd).